# TCP socket not reading the 2nd response

Tags: java, tcp, openflow

Trying to implement a Openflow Controller using Java TCP socket programming.

I receive the hello packet from OVS and respond with a Hello and Feature Request. I can receive the Feature-response on my device(confirmed from wireshark), but not my Java code does read the packet.

I create a thread for every Openflow packet hitting the socket.
Using the thread I read the contents using InputStream read(). In the thread I send the response to OVS with Hello and Feature Request.

I can see that Java program is not receiving the Feature Response as I try to print every packet I receive.

Can the TCP socket drop packets?

```
while (true) {
        socket = null;
        try {
            System.out.println("Waiting....");
            socket = serverSocket.accept();
            System.out.println("Client connected");
            String line = String.valueOf(socket.getInputStream());
            System.out.println(line);
            //InputStream is = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
            //OutputStream os = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
            Thread t = new handler(socket);
            t.start();
        } catch (IOException  e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Thread Class:

```
public handler(Socket s) throws IOException {
    this.s = s;
    this.is = new DataInputStream(s.getInputStream());
    this.os = new DataOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());
}
public void run() {
    try {


        byte[] array = new byte[is.available()];

        is.read(array);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        int i = 0;
        for (byte b : array) {
            if (i % 10 == 0) {
                System.out.println();
            }
            sb.append(String.format("%02x", b & 0xff));
            i++;
        }
        System.out.println(sb.toString());
        if (sb.subSequence(2, 4).equals("00")) {

            os.write(new byte[]{4, 0, 0, 8, 0, 0, 1, (byte) 34});
            os.flush();
            os.write(new byte[]{4, 5, 0, 8, (byte) 255, (byte) 255, (byte) 255, (byte) 254});
            os.flush();
        }
        is.close();
        os.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I dont see any error for the response from the Switch.

Comment: how do you connect to the server? any client code?

Comment: I have OVS switch configured on a VM. I direct the Switch to connect to the controller which is my Java code.
"sudo ovs-vsctl set-controller br0 tcp:<IP address>:5555"
Above are my ip and the port.
The Switch would send the request and the conversation starts.

Comment: so what does that switch expect to receive from server?

Comment: The Switch expects to receive the below data from the controller:
os.write(new byte[]{4, 0, 0, 8, 0, 0, 1, (byte) 34});
            os.flush();
            os.write(new byte[]{4, 5, 0, 8, (byte) 255, (byte) 255, (byte) 255, (byte) 254});
            os.flush();

The switch recevies it and also responds with the a proper response to the controller. But my Java code cannot read that response. 
But taking a wireshark trace, I can see the response from the switch hitting my device on the intended for the socket.

Comment: so after getting those messages it responds with something? but you never read that response in your server - you close your streams after sending those two byte arrays

Comment: True, I close them. But it is in a separate thread. My main thread should still read the response and create a new thread. Is my thinking right?

Comment: no. your main thread will accept another connection for a new message exchange. it has nothing to do with the previous connection. so that message coming from the switch is simply lost. you should close your input stream only after you receive a response

Comment: OH!Amazing, I understood now. Thanks a lot! :)

Comment: Get rid of the `available()` call. You need to block in the read until data actually arrives, and you need to store the result of `read()` in a variable so you can test it and use it if positive. NB Taking `toString()` of the input stream is meaningless.